# Is there a way to import functions with decorators in python for discord bots

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Like said in the title, if it's possible I'd like to be able to import some part of code that contains decorators in the bot code.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Updates(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    prefix = '!'
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(
        prefix), description='Useless - Updates')
    bot.add_cog(Updates(bot))
    bot.run(token)
```

I have like 3 or more sub-modules like that (I have a main file that check for modules that query for the class, here 'Updates') and I have a common part of code :

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return
    raise error

@commands.group(name='stop', hidden=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def stop(self, ctx):

    await ctx.message.add_reaction('\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}')
    await self.bot.logout()
    sys.exit()

@commands.group(name='reload', hidden=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(self, ctx):

    await ctx.message.add_reaction('\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}')
    await self.bot.logout()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, __file__])
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html). These are basically classes which function as "groupings" for commands. Such classes can then be added via `bot.add_cog(YourCogClass(bot))`

A much more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528504/12002411).

Comment: That not worked as expected for the reload command but thanks, I didn't though that'll be that simple. I will try to work around that problem..

Comment: Actually, sys.argv[0] do the work, I changed __file to sys.argv[0]