# How to get your Discord bot to say something specific, then delete the previous message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im new to working with discord.py, basically im simply trying to make my discord bot say something then delete the previous text, so for example I want to type "/say hello" then I want the bot to grab that, remove the prefix and just print "hello", Ive already googled and searched and found another guide but there was no follow up answers and when I tried the solutions they errored, below is the code im using

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Client()
prefix = "/"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "say"):
        await bot.delete_message(message)
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))

bot.run("token")
```

and this is the error the console prints out

```
C:\Users\unknownuser\anaconda3\envs\discordbot\pythonw.exe C:/Users/unknownuser/PycharmProjects/discordbot/bot.py
Online
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unknownuser\anaconda3\envs\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 313, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/unknownuser/PycharmProjects/discordbot/bot.py", line 15, in on_message
    await bot.delete_message(message)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'delete_message'
```

As I start learning the documentation and logic behind it I should start figuring it out for myself but this one has me stumped, Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using a tutorial for an old version of discord.py.
There are some [major changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) in the most recent - rewrite - version.

## Example for your code

```py
# using the command decorator
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, sentence):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(sentence)

#############################################

# using the on_message event
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "say"):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(" ".join(args))
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message) # allows decorated commands to work
```

---

**References:**

- [`Message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Comment: Thanks, I did end up getting it working after reading through the documentation, sort of one of those things where you try figure it out, give up. then while waiting for someone to help you, you figure it out.

just to add, can you explain the different between using the message event and the command detector

Comment: When using decorators, it's much easier to organise your code - especially for larger bots. It enables you to split your code up into "[cogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py)" (just different modules), and looks much neater. It is also much, much easier to deal with arguments.