# How to toggle trigger Cog listener with command in discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a discord bot where when you type the command `!purge` in the desired channel, it will constantly delete all the messages sent, and when you type it again, it will stop deleting all the messages.

From learning online I know I have to use a Cog listener, but I don't exactly know how to "trigger" it with a command. I would need the `@commands.Cog.listener()` paragraph to use the `on_message` listener, but I also can't figure out how I would get it to delete messages in the channel where the command `!purge` was executed.

I tried already using a boolean value to toggle on and off when the command was typed and it would use a while loop to constantly delete messages, but then the while loop would stop. It might have been because the session of the command expired, not sure about that though.

Any thoughts on how I can use get this working? More specifically, how I can somehow link the Cog to the command? Thanks!

(Edits of my code I tried to use to be here but I have deleted them because of irrelevancy)

**Cog Thread I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528504/11805086**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to create a trigger command, which enables or disables the purge mode and then, in your `on_message` function, you'd have to check if the purge mode is enabled or not.

Here's how to do it (within a cog):
**Edited by poster**

- In cogs.py

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Purge_Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.channels = {}

    @commands.command()
    async def purge(self, ctx):
        try:
            if self.channels[ctx.channel]:
                self.channels[ctx.channel] = False
                await ctx.channel.send("Purge mode disabled!")
            else:
                self.channels[ctx.channel] = True
                await ctx.channel.send("Purge mode enabled!")
        except:
           self.channels[ctx.channel] = True
           await ctx.channel.send("Purge mode enabled!")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        try:
            if self.channels[message.channel]:
                await message.channel.purge(limit=999)
        except:
            pass

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Purge_Cog(bot))
```

- In your main file add this (bot.py or main.py)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

initial_extensions = ['cogs.cogs']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)

bot.run('Your token')
```

Comment: Last thing, I need to create a list of boolean values for the purging for each channel, because the purge boolean is universal across all channels. I am having trouble with the if statements and changing boolean values for each `ctx.channel`. Any thoughts?

Comment: My bad ^^. I changed the post. Hopefully, it's the last edit. PS : Once it's over, you can delete your comments (so those who'll see this post don't loose time or get lost)

Comment: For some reason, the command doesn't work. No output from the mode messages either, troubleshooting right now. Double checked that the code was correct. @Mr_Spaar

Comment: I miss spelled `except` and replaced `self.channels[ctx.channel]` to `self.channels[message.channel]` in `on_message`