# How can I use advanced command handling in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So my bot is starting to have a lot of commands, and it's getting a bit messy on main.py. I know there's a way to store the commands in other files and then apply them to main.py when they are triggered on discord.js. Is it possible on discord.py as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use cogs with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are these things called "cogs", you can have a cog for events and some for other categories.
Here's an example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class ExampleCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command() # You use commands.command() instead of bot.command()
    async def test(self, ctx): # you must always have self, if not it will not work.
        await ctx.send("**Test**")

    @commands.Cog.listener() # You use commands.Cog.listener() instead of bot.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Test")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ExampleCog(bot))
```

Whenever you use `bot` replace it with `self.bot` when you're using cogs.
When you are using cogs, you need to have the cog files in a separate folder.
You should make a folder called "`./cogs/examplecog.py`"

In your main bot file, you should have the code that is written below in order for the bot to read the cog files.

```py
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"): # lists all the cog files inside the cog folder.
    if file.endswith(".py"): # It gets all the cogs that ends with a ".py".
        name = file[:-3] # It gets the name of the file removing the ".py"
        await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}") # This loads the cog.
```

A benefit of having cogs is you don't need to restart the bot every time you want the new code to work, you just do `!reload <cogname>`, `!unload <cogname>`, or `!load <cogname>` and for those commands to work you need the code that is below.

Reload Cog Below

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        await bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog reloaded')
```

Unload Cog Below

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        await bot.unload_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog unloaded')
```

Load Cog Below

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog loaded')
```

Note:
The code might not work with slash commands to ensure that it does, use `@bot.tree.app_command()` instead of `@bot.command()` and `@app_command()` instead of `@commands.command()` for discord.py 2.0 to work normally with slash commands.

I hope you understood all of this.
*it took me about an hour to write this.*

You can get more help from Senarc on this [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/5YY3W83YWg)

Finally, Have a nice day, and best of luck with your bot.