# Command not found error when i put command into a separate file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently just tried to clean up my main.py file because there is lots of code in it. I wanted to store every command into a file. I started with the clear/purge command. Whenever i type `>clean`, i get the error, "command not found". How do i fix this? Code for some of the main.py and clear.py is below. Any help would be appreciated! :D

**MAIN.PY**

```
import discord
from discord import User
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import requests
import json
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Greedy
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
 print('The bot is online')
 await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('>help | Bot made by ColeTMK'))
```

**CLEAR.PY**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')

class Clear():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
 await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Clear Messages", description=f'{amount} messages were deleted!', color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await asyncio.sleep(3)
 await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Clear(bot))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use cogs with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: better solution using COGS

Actually discord.py allows "cogs", see documentation here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html

here is an example too: https://gist.github.com/leovoel/46cd89ed6a8f41fd09c5

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.. it says that import clear is unused.

Comment: its not working because you aren't using the same bot instance, you defined bot in your main.py and in your clear.py. I would suggest passing the bot as a parameter.

Comment: So passing bot as a parameter in my clear.py file or main.py file?

Comment: updated my answer to use cogs instead of same bot instance.

Comment: @Stoobish Ok i think i added this cog correctly.. If i did.. I still get the error saying that >clear is not a command. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @ColeTMK Your code is not following the same structure as the example I provided. On first glance, I noticed your functions aren't part of your Clear class. Compare what you have to the example.

Comment: @Stoobish Wdym by this? I looked at the example and i think i have what it has. Do i need to add the extension part that is in the main.py example? Sorry, im brand new to this.

Comment: @ColeTMK your `clear` function isn't defined in the Clear class

also you'll need to load the Clear extension in your main.py
`bot.load_extension(extension)` before you run `bot.run('token')`.

Its also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py

Comment: @Stoobish I looked at this and i tried but im SOO confused at where everything goes and what needs to go where.. is there a way we can talk somewhere else about this? maybe discord or something? But i really appreciate you helping me out!

Comment: @ColeTMK what are you confused about? I do have discord btw but maybe I can explain here

Comment: @Stoobish Like where the classes go and the def bot part. Like where goes go in my main.py or the other folders.

Comment: @ColeTMK I moved this discussion to a stackoverflow chat, so join there and I can answer all your questions

Comment: @Stoobish Where is that at?

Comment: @ColeTMK https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231905/discussion-between-coletmk-and-stoobish