# Passing context parameter from commands of a discord bot to own function

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, bots, parameter-passing

I am working on a discord bot and was able to add some commands to it using [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) from `discord.ext`. Here an example of my current code:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

# define commands
@commands.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('some answer by the bot')

client.add_command(start)
```

So this works as expected, but now I try to pass the `ctx` to my own function and use it there. This don't work like I want. The goal is to check for a specific `discord user id` before starting some action.

```
def start_bot(bot_token : str):

    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

    # define commands
    @commands.command()
    async def start(ctx):
        start_command(ctx)

    client.add_command(start)

    # run the bot
    client.run(bot_token)

def start_command(ctx):
    
    user_id = ctx.message.author.id
    
    if user_id == 1234:
        print('1234')
        # do some other stuff
    else:
        print('error')
        # do some other stuff
```

Do I need to use `await` and `async`?
Btw: My bot does not crash, it just never prints one of my 2 statements in my `start_command(ctx)` function.

Comment: Why are you using ```commands.command()``` when you have defined ```client``` as your bot?

Comment: You mean because I could use `@client.command()`? referring to [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) it is equivalent

Comment: `commands.command` is used in `Cogs`. It does not look like you are using one, correct me if I am wrong. If you defined `client` and do not use `Cogs` you can't use `commands.command`...

Comment: @Dominik you're wrong, `Cogs` is not needed, he can use it.

Comment: @Gvinfinity You can't use `commands.command` outside a `Cog`... Have a look at [How do I use cogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py).

Comment: @Dominik, you literally can, I'm using it in one of my bots, OP already answered that it's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out by myself now. using `commands.command()` was not the issue.
First of all I need to call my function:

```
@commands.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await start_command(ctx)
```

and than my function needs to be `async`:

```
async def start_command(ctx):

    welcome_message = 'Welcome!'
    # do some other stuff

    await ctx.send(welcome_message)
```