# Lock command - Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is my lock command

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def lock(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None, reason: str = None):
        channel = ctx.channel or channel

        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
        await ctx.send(f"{success} | **{ctx.author.name}**, successfully locked <#{channel.id}>",
                       ephemeral=True)

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Channel locked",
            description=f"This channel was locked by {ctx.author.mention} ",
            color=embed_color
        )
        embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=reason.capitalize())
        embed.add_field(name=":warning: | Important", value="**Users with Administrator perms won't be affected**",
                        inline=False)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

It works but if the channel is private (so `@everyone` can't see the channel), the bot sets it a public even if in the code (where it overwrites permissions) I don't have `view_channel=True`. Any ideas to solve?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you can do `channel.mention` instead of `<#{channel.id}>`

Comment: Maybe when you do `set_permissions` it defaults `view_channel=True`, so try explicitly setting it to `False`? Unfortunately I can't find reference in the documentation if this is the case.

Comment: But if a channel is visible to everyone before being blocked (so `@everyone` can see it), if I put `view_channel=False` then `@everyone` no longer sees it. And that's the problem.

Comment: You could try PermissionOverwrites - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions

Comment: I tried with `PermissionOverwrites` but it is the same :|

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code here, instead of mentioning a channel or using the channel id you can just use the command and it locks the channel you type lock in

**CODE:**

```
    @commands.command(aliases=["l"])
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(client, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None, reason = None
):
          """Lock the current channel """
          await ctx.message.delete()
          embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Channel locked",
            description=f"This channel was locked by {ctx.author.mention} ",
            color=embed_color
        )
          embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=reason.capitalize())
          embed.add_field(name=":warning: | Important", value="**Users with Administrator perms won't be affected**",
                        inline=False)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
          overwrite = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
          overwrite.send_messages = False
          await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
```

You need the message to be sent before the lock, so that when the channel is locked, the bot can still type that its locked, because if it locks before it sends it, then the bot must have administrator perms

I also gave the command permissions, you can obviuosly get rid of that, same with the cooldown line, i was just showing you options to add to moderation commands

Comment: If you are using cogs, why is there no ```self``` argument in the function?

Comment: self is only used for the ```@commands.Cogs.listener``` code, you just need to call client in your argument

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py) out. I could be wrong though.. I don't have experience with cogs but I have seen that in cogs even for the commands there is a ```self``` argument.

Comment: ive never used them as long as it works it works

Comment: The bot has the administrator permission, so this is not a real problem. My "real" problem is when it overwrites permissions, especially when a channel is private, the bot makes it public.

Comment: like when you unlock it?