# nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "roles" is not found

Tags: python, discord, command, bots, nextcord

> Problem : nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command
> "roles" is not  found

cog.py file:

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
from button_roles.role_view import RoleView

class ButtonRoles(commands.Cog, name="Board Roles"):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):    
        self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    self.bot.add_view(RoleView())
     
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def roles(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Click a button to add or remove a role.", view=RoleView())

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(ButtonRoles(bot))
```

role_view.py file:

```
    import nextcord
from bot import custom_id
import config

VIEW_NAME = "RoleView"

class RoleView(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    

@nextcord.ui.button(label="NSFW", emoji=":dart:", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id=custom_id(VIEW_NAME, config.NSFW_ROLE_ID))
async def nsfw_button(self, button, interaction):
        interaction.response.send_message("Ты получил NSFW роль")
```

bot.py file

```
from code import interact
from unicodedata import name
from nextcord.ext import commands
import config
import os
import nextcord
import textwrap
import requests, json, random, datetime, asyncio
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from nextcord import File, ButtonStyle, Interaction, ChannelType, SlashOption
from nextcord.ui import Button, View
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, intents=intents)
serverID = config.GUILD_ID
BOT_NAME = config.BOT_NAME

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")

@bot.slash_command(name="add", guild_ids = [serverID])
async def add(ctx, left: int, right: int):
    """Слаживать левое и правое число"""
    await ctx.send(left + right)

@bot.slash_command(name="splx", guild_ids = [serverID])
async def _bot(ctx):
    """Вся инфа"""
    await ctx.send("Читается как Суплекс а не спликс")  

def custom_id(view: str, id: int) -> str:
    return f"{config.BOT_NAME}:{view}:{id}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

***Bot successfully running without problems, and others commands running also without mistakes, however instead of $roles one
I need to know how to make a bot able to react to a trigger $roles, thanks (i'm new in discord bots developing so sorry bcs of my stupism)***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use cogs with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py)

Comment: You haven't loaded the cogs

Answer (score 0):

well, the commands was indented incorrectly in the cog file.

you should make the commands defined in the cog file in the cog defination, like this:

```py
class ABC(commands.Cog):
  ...

  # like this, the commands defination should be cog defination indent level+1
  @commands.command()
  ...

# NOT like this
@commands.command()
...
```