# Extentions and Cogs not working in discord.py v2.1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get export my commands in a discord bot I run to a new file, using cogs and extensions. However, the commands do not register, and I'm not sure why. I'll send the code here.

```
#bot.py
import json
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


# prefix
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix=get_prefix, self_bot=True, strip_after_prefix = True)


# cogs
@client.command()
async def load(extension):
    await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')


@client.command()
async def unload(extension):
    await client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')


async def load_extension():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print('Task 1/6: Logged in as: {0.user.name} Bots user id: {0.user.id}'.format(client))


client.run("my token")
```

This is my cogs

```
#Onstart.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class onstart(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as: {0.user.name}\nBots user id: {0.user.id}'.format(self.client))
        print('Discord.py version:')
        print(discord.__version__)
        print('Ready!')

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Ping is {round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms')

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(onstart(client))
    print("Task 2/6: Onstart.py loaded")
```

I have tried to read https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html

Comment: Where do you actually call ```load_extension()```?

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) Yes, and I'm not sure about Cogs, but I guess you also have to `import` `Onstart.py` in your `bot.py` or `bot.py` in `Onstart.py` for your classes and commands/functions to work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py). It says you have to `load_extension(cogsfilename)` with `cogsfilename` as `Onstart.py` in your case. Please see [ask] and [mcve] and other answers before asking similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example this should work

```py
#bot.py
import json
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


# prefix
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

intents = discord.Intents.all()

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            intents=intents, 
            command_prefix=get_prefix, 
            self_bot=True, strip_after_prefix = True
        )


client = Bot()



# cogs
@client.command()
async def load(extension):
    await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')


@client.command()
async def unload(extension):
    await client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')


async def load_extension():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print('Task 1/6: Logged in as: {0.user.name} Bots user id: {0.user.id}'.format(client))


client.run("my token")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).