# Error while importing functions from a module (File)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to import my database file (python file) in my 'ticketcreate' although all permissions are right, import names are right, I get an error indicating that it cannot import the functions in the file.

The following is the error i'm receiving when trying to run the bot, it should be creating a new .db file with tables inside of it.

> Failed to load extension ticketCreate: Extension 'Features.ticketCreate' raised an error: ImportError: cannot import name 'createFoolbluhh' from 'Features.foolbluhh' (D:\Discord Bots\FoolBluhhh\Features\foolbluhh.py)
> Loaded extension: __init__*

The code below is the code used in the ticketcreate.py file to import my functions:

```
from Features.foolbluhh import createFoolbluhh,createServers, createTickets
```

This is my database file setup:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import aiosqlite
class FoolBluhh(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        async def createFoolbluhh(self):
            print('e')
            async with aiosqlite.connect('Databases/foolbluhh.db') as db_connection:
                pass  

        async def createServers(self):
            async with aiosqlite.connect('Databases/foolbluhh.db') as db_connection:
                db_cursor = await db_connection.cursor()
                await db_cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Servers (
                    serverID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    serverName TEXT,
                    serverPanMsgID INTEGER,
                    serverTicketIDs INTEGER
                )''')
                await db_connection.commit()
                print("Servers tablee created successfully.")
        async def createTickets(self):
            async with aiosqlite.connect('Databases/foolbluhh.db') as db_connection:
                db_cursor = await db_connection.cursor()
                await db_cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tickets (
                    serverTicketID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    ticketOpenerName TEXT,
                    ticketOpenerID INTEGER,
                    ticketCreationDate TEXT,
                    ticketCloseDate TEXT
                )''')
                await db_connection.commit()
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(FoolBluhh(bot))
```

As said, It does not make the file nor does it put anything inside if I make the file myself.
I should add that my file structure looks like this:
[ticketcreate and database code files in features folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovJC6.png)

Comment: I think it's because you cannot import functions that are inside a class. The 3 methods you're trying to import are inside the FoolBluhh class. Also the functions seem to be inside the `__init__` function but should be outside that function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528168/how-do-i-use-cogs-with-discord-py The answer to this question has a nice simple tutorial on using cogs.

Comment: I read over your link & the docs on that link but I never found the solution I was looking for. I also tried removing my database functions outside of the __init__ function at the top although got error:
Failed to load extension foolbluhh: Extension 'Features.foolbluhh' raised an error: AttributeError: 'FoolBluhh' object has no attribute 'createFoolbluhh'

What would be a workaround to remove them from the class or import all functions inside that class and be able to call them in my ticketcreate file?